# What chrome flags that I should enable/disable to improve puppeteer performance?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

It seems like chrome/chromium by default have some features enabled that decrease the browser performance that may not be important in the context of puppeteer.

I'm using puppeteer to only scrape some trust worthy websites, so security should not be a priority.

For example, from chromium documentation, having `--disable-features=site-per-process` flag, decrease memory usage by more than 10%, this is a great deal for me especially since I'm running puppeteer on a Raspberry Pi 3. I know that this decrease the security of the browser, but as I said, I'm only visiting trust worthy sites.

Is there any other flags or features that I can disable that will improve performance or decrease memory usage even at the cost of security?